# SteamStartup failed with error 108 - Django

Tags: django, command-line, python-3.x

I'm new to python and django, and I'm trying to start a new project. I'm using Eclipse with Django, but when creating a new project the none of the settings.py or models.py files are created (only the `init.py`). So I tried creating the project/app from the command line and all I'm getting is this error.

I've not been able to find anything related to this, since every time I run the command the code in the brackets changes and the errors are relating to the gaming software Steam.
The only thing I've found so far is that there's a possibility of the .dll being duplicated on the path, but it's not.

I've also tried `startapp` and `startproject` and I get the same error on both.

[image: Screenshot]

The cmd on the left was opened from the directory on the right.

**Edit:** I've found the problem, which was that in the properties this was opening as a .hl2 file; associated with steam. However now I'm not sure what type of file it's supposed to be to in the properties. I put it as a notepad file, but it just opens the file in notepad when running the command. I changed it to run the Python.exe and it worked.

Comment: eclipse creates only the packages for you. You need to add the py files in yourself. Look into django-skel app for the basic scaffolding.

Comment: I've looked at this, downloaded it, installed it through pip but when running `python create_pkg.py` it's saying virtualenv is required. I installed that and it's still giving me the same error. Also looking at this site for the skeleton projects it's coming up as unsupported for Python 3.3: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/project-templates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this problem Disable UAC (User Account Control). Being a security feature in the Windows it prevents certain execution of suspicious game files.

> Click the Start button.
>
> Click Control Panel | User Accounts and Family Safety | User Accounts.
>
> Click “Change User Account Control settings”.
>
> Move the slider to extreme bottom. This will disable UAC.
>
> Click OK | Close.

If issue still exists then for more helpful tips click here:
**[Error 108](http://www.optimum-systems.com/2013/08/error-108-in-diablo-3-why-you-need-to.html)**